# Console error unknow, csp_whitelist?

Tags: magento2.3

magento 2 site updated to version 2.3.5-p1, checking with the chrome browser console, I encountered an error that I did not understand.
In particular, the error refers to a link that I had never seen before:

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://data1.moiziq.com/scripts/js?k=5c9f3a89f3c82d08658b4568&s=d3d3LmZvcm5hY2ViZXNhbnphLml0' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com video.google.com vimeo.com www.vimeo.com js.authorize.net jstest.authorize.net js.braintreegateway.com cdn-scripts.signifyd.com www.youtube.com *.googleapis.com google.com *.gstatic.com cdn.ampproject.org connect.facebook.net www.googletagmanager.com googletagmanager.com *.kxcdn.com platform.twitter.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Can you help me understand what it is and if anything solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this module: https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_ext_csp

It collect all the report and after create the csp_whitelist rules.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.3.5, Magento supports CSP headers and provides ways to configure them.

> Content Security Policies (CSP) are a powerful tool to mitigate
>   against Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and related attacks, including card
>   skimmers, session hijacking, clickjacking, and more.

By default CSP is set to **report only** mode, so what you are seeing in the console logs are not exactly Magento errors but rather reports of detected content security policy violations by the CSP module.

You can configure CSP to whitelist certain services, domains and content or use a third party to log and audit these security policy reports.

You can learn more about how to do this via the official documentation at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html

Comment: Hi, thanks to answare, I read the devdocs, but I don't understund if I create one csp_whitelist.xml file or every extension must have own. Can you help me on this point?

Comment: Hi, I solved using this module: https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_ext_csp